# Recursion depth issue using Python with DFS algorithm

Tags: algorithm, python-3.x, recursion

The DFS algorithm is already working with small test cases, but when I run it with a huge sample it throws "RuntimeError: maximum recursion depth exceeded", so I included `sys.setrecursionlimit(10 ** 6)` and the system throws this message: "python.exe stopped working" and PyCharm throws the message: "Process finished with exit code -1073741571 (0xC00000FD)".
You can download a zip file of the [sample](https://github.com/xRam0n/DFS/blob/master/SCC.zip?raw=true).

Code:

```
import sys
import threading

threading.stack_size(67108864)
sys.setrecursionlimit(10 ** 6)


def get_input(filename):
    graph_map = {}

    for line in open(filename, 'r').readlines():
        values = [int(val) for val in line.split()]
        key1 = values.pop(0)
        key2 = values.pop(0)

        if not key1 in graph_map:
            graph_map[key1] = []

        if not key2 in graph_map:
            graph_map[key2] = []

        graph_map[key1].extend([key2])

    return graph_map


def DFS(graph_map, start):
    global visited

    visited[start-1] = True

    for child in graph_map[start]:
        if visited[child-1] is False:
            DFS(graph_map, child)


def DFS_Loop(graph_map):
    global visited

    i = len(graph_map)  # max(graph_map.keys())
    for i in reversed(range(1, i+1)):
        if visited[i-1] is False:
            DFS(graph_map, i)


graph_map = get_input("SCC.txt")
visited = [False]*len(graph_map)  # size of the graph
DFS_Loop(graph_map)
```

Is there any way of achieving this without taking away the recursion?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One of the cool things about Python is that iterators are just a normal datatype. Although one usually uses for loops and comprehensions to iterate, there is nothing to stop you from doing the iteration manually if that is convenient. One reason it might be convenient is to avoid deep recursion, by replacing it with an explicit stack.

While this does "take away the recursion", it does not significantly complicate the program, and the recursive structure is still evident. Python simply does not recurse gracefully, so this sort of transformation is often useful.

When you write

```
for child in graph_map[start]:
    ...
```

You're doing something very similar to the following:

```
it = iter(graph_map[start])
try:
  child = next(it)
  ...
except StopIteration:
  pass
```

[See Note 1]

The `iter` function returns an iterator for a collection (or other iterable object, such as a comprehension, a generator, or a range). The `next` method returns the next value, and advances the iterator; if there is no next value, a `StopIteration` exception is raised.

The DFS function simply calls itself recursively for every unvisited child of its argument. We can emulate that behaviour precisely using a stack of iterators. Instead of recursively calling with a node, we'll push an iterator to the node's children onto the iterator stack. When the iterator at the top of the stack terminates, we'll pop it off the stack.

```
def DFS(graph_map):
  visited = [False] * len(graph_map)
  # By initializing the stack with a range iterator, we do
  # the equivalent of DFS_Loop.
  # In Python2, you should use xrange instead of range
  stack = [iter(range(len(graph_map), 0, -1))]
  while stack:
    try:
      child = next(stack[-1])
      if not visited[child - 1]:
        visited[child - 1] = True
        # Do whatever you want to do in the visit
        stack.append(iter(graph_map[child]))
    except StopIteration:
      stack.pop()
```

The above function applied to the sample data in the file provided in the OP used a maximum of 62794 stack slots. On my Linux laptop, it took somewhere around 3 seconds, once the data was read in; I didn't time it precisely.

It's also interesting to note that the above can be changed to do a breadth-first search simply by changing the stack to a queue. For a depth search first, the stack *must* be a stack of iterators (or equivalent, in languages in which that is not so simple); for breadth-search first, the queue *may* be a queue of iterators, but it would work as well to use a queue of values.

---

#### Notes

1. The actual virtual machine uses the defined iterator protocol, which varies slightly between Python2 and Python3. In both versions, the container (or other iterable) objection has a member function called `__iter__` which returns a newly created iterator object. The iterator object has a method called `next` in Python2 and `__next__` in Python3, which returns the current value and advances the iterator. Since 2.6, you can use the `iter` and `next` global functions to avoid having to worry about these details, and that's what I've done here.

Comment: good answer, In fact you solved  other question that I had about How implement DFS with a Stack, thanks. Just to clarify that xrange() was renamed to range() in Python 3(see more here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17192158/nameerror-global-name-xrange-is-not-defined) and as you see in my tags I use python 3.4

Comment: @GuillermoAyranTorresLores: That's exactly why I included the comment ` # In Python3, you need to use range instead of xrange `. Sorry for not noticing the tag.

Comment: True, sorry, I hadn't noticed

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the system stack limit. On linux you can do it this way:

`ulimit -s 1000000` (for windows check [here](https://superuser.com/questions/340239/how-to-increase-stack-size-permanently-on-windows-7))

Then I ran your program, it exited normally.

Comment: I forgot to say that I'm running it on Windows

Comment: The default recursion limit (at least on Windows) is 1000. I have set it as high as 10000.  That should be enough for a graph with any degree of branching.  The maximum depth for a linear chain graph is the number of nodes.  So try something less than 1000000.