# Name 'xrange' is not defined in Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, range, xrange

I try to execute following code but can't with mistake: name 'xrange' is not defined

```
pages = (
    requests.get(
        build_group_request({
            "offset": WINDOW_SIZE * i,
            "count": WINDOW_SIZE,
            "fields": "sex,interests,bdate"
        })
    ).json()['response']['items']
    for i in xrange(int(float(COUNT) / 100 + 1))
)
```

Comment: Are you in python 3?

Comment: Refer to: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/135041/should-you-always-favor-xrange-over-range

Comment: @Jello `xrange` doesn't exist in python 3 anymore you can use `range` instead

Comment: Duplicate (not to mention the first hit for *"python nameerror xrange"*... come on): http://stackoverflow.com/q/17192158/3001761

Answer (score 59):

You're probably using Python3, where `xrange` has become `range`.

Comment: Is it equivalent? Can I replace `xrange` in a python 2.x code with `range` so it works in python 3.x?

Comment: @A.Vieira You must, not *can*