# Problems with Python script

Tags: python, xml

I've come up with this python code that is supposed to take a text file with thousands of RSS urls (one per line) and create one XML file PER 500 lines.

Here is what I have so far:

```
urls = open('file.txt','r').read().splitlines()
opml = open('opml.xml','w')


opml.write('<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>\n<opml version="1.0">\n<head>\n<title>My Rss list</title>\n</head>\n<body>\n')
for i in xrange(500):
    opml.write('<outline title="RSS Site %d" type="rss" xmlUrl = "%s"/>\n'%(i + 1, urls[i]))
opml.write('</body>\n</opml>')
opml.close()
```

But it's got problems, the result file ends up looking like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<opml version="1.0">
<head>
<title>My Rss list</title>
</head>
<body>
```

It is missing the closing body and the closing opml, and obviously it's missing the outline bits.

In the python shell, when I run the script I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last): File "C:/Users/nzbit/Desktop/Convert To OPML Python Test/converttoopml.py", line 6, in <module> for i in xrange(500): NameError: name 'xrange' is not defined
```

UPDATE: Here is the latest issue in the produced XML files:

```
<outline title="RSS Site 1" type="rss" xmlUrl = "��tp://www.gardenleisurepools.com/forum/external?type=rss2"/>
<outline title="RSS Site 2" type="rss" xmlUrl = ""/>
<outline title="RSS Site 3" type="rss" xmlUrl = "http://www.meguiarsonline.com/forum/external.php?type=RSS2"/>
<outline title="RSS Site 4" type="rss" xmlUrl = ""/>
<outline title="RSS Site 5" type="rss" xmlUrl = "http://www.newportri.com/board/external?type=rss2"/>
<outline title="RSS Site 6" type="rss" xmlUrl = ""/>
<outline title="RSS Site 7" type="rss" xmlUrl = "http://www.abandonware-forums.org/forums/external?type=rss2"/>
<outline title="RSS Site 8" type="rss" xmlUrl = ""/>
<outline title="RSS Site 9" type="rss" xmlUrl = "https://www.lrcsite.com/forum/external.php?type=RSS2"/>
<outline title="RSS Site 10" type="rss" xmlUrl = ""/>
<outline title="RSS Site 11" type="rss" xmlUrl = "http://www.accutane-recall.com/forums/external?type=rss2"/>
```

Comment: it seems that there is no content in your `file.txt`?

Comment: There definitely is, but remember it's not just the content from the file.txt that's missing, it's also the closing body and the closing opml etc

Comment: if `urls[i]` raise error, the consequence code will not execute.

Comment: In the python shell, when I run the script I get this error: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/nzbit/Desktop/Convert To OPML Python Test/converttoopml.py", line 6, in <module>
    for i in xrange(500):
NameError: name 'xrange' is not defined

Comment: Possible duplicate of [NameError: global name 'xrange' is not defined in Python 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17192158/nameerror-global-name-xrange-is-not-defined-in-python-3)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you are running your code in python3 not python2, you have to change `xrange()` to `range()` in Python 3:

```
for i in range(500):
```

**Update:** this is roughly idea based on your code, it will create multiple file like `opml1.xml,opml2.xml,opml3.xml`... and write with content per 500 lines. As your `file.txt` is encoding with `UCS-2`, it is [utf-16](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-16), you can open file with `encoding='utf-16'` like this, then there will be no special characters.

```
with open('file.txt', encoding='utf-16') as f: #open with utf-16
    urls = f.read().splitlines()
fileNum=1
for i in range(500,len(urls)+500,500): #loop with per 500
    with open('opml'+str(fileNum)+'.xml','w') as opml:
        opml.write('<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>\n<opml version="1.0">\n<head>\n<title>My Rss list</title>\n</head>\n<body>\n')
        if i >len(urls):
            for j in range(i-500,len(urls)):
                opml.write('<outline title="RSS Site %d" type="rss" xmlUrl = "%s"/>\n'%(j + 1, urls[j]))
        else:
            for j in range(i-500,i):
                opml.write('<outline title="RSS Site %d" type="rss" xmlUrl = "%s"/>\n'%(j + 1, urls[j]))
        opml.write('</body>\n</opml>')
        opml.close()
    fileNum+=1 #increase file number per loop
```

Answer (score 0):

this working for me without issues:

```
urls = open('file.txt','r').read().splitlines()
opml = open('opml.xml','w')


opml.write('<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>\n<opml version="1.0">\n<head>\n<title>My Rss list</title>\n</head>\n<body>\n')
for i in range(500):
    if len(urls) > i:
        opml.write('<outline title="RSS Site %d" type="rss" xmlUrl = "%s"/>\n'%(i + 1, urls[i]))
    else:
        break
opml.write('</body>\n</opml>')
opml.close()
```

run file as python3