# Asking for unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'range' and 'list'

Tags: python, python-3.x, range, shuffle

I am trying to run the following code but there was an error. The following code was run in for Python3 using Spyder.

```
def create_batches(data_size, batch_size, shuffle=True):
    """create index by batches."""
    batches = []
    ids = range(data_size)
    if shuffle:
        random.shuffle(ids)
    for i in range(data_size // batch_size):
        start = i * batch_size
        end = (i + 1) * batch_size
        batches.append(ids[start:end])
    # the batch of which the length is less than batch_size
    rest = data_size % batch_size
    if rest > 0:
         batches.append(ids[-rest:] + [-1] * (batch_size - rest))  # -1 as padding
    return batches
```

The errror was:

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'range' and 'list'
```

Does anyone know how to solve this problem?

Comment: The error you do get by running this code is: `TypeError: 'range' object does not support item assignment`. Wondering where did you get `TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'range' and 'list'`?

Comment: In line 3: ids = range(data_size)

Comment: No, you did not! You do get error in this line: `random.shuffle(ids)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`random.shuffle()` only works on *mutable sequences*, which is usually a `list` object. `range()` produces an *immutable* sequence object, `random.shuffle()` can't move the values in a range around.

Convert the range to a list first:

```
ids = list(range(data_size))
```

In Python 2, `range()` used to produce a list of integers (vs. `xrange()`, producing the immutable sequence), so you can still find code online that uses `range()` without `list()` before shuffling. Take this into account when trying to adapt online code examples to Python 3. Also see [NameError: global name 'xrange' is not defined in Python 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17192158/nameerror-global-name-xrange-is-not-defined-in-python-3)

Comment: Thank you Mr. Martijn Pieters. Now it works. I am very happy. :D