# How do I fill in this incomplete script to return the sum of all divisors that are given?

Tags: python

```
def sum_divisors(n):
  sum = 0
  # Return the sum of all divisors of n, not including n
  return sum

print(sum_divisors(0))
# 0
print(sum_divisors(3)) # Should sum of 1
# 1
print(sum_divisors(36)) # Should sum of 1+2+3+4+6+9+12+18
# 55
print(sum_divisors(102)) # Should be sum of 2+3+6+17+34+51
# 114
```

I attempted to find the range of the numbers with this that I found on another question asked on here but I'm honestly just completely stumped with this question that I'm being asked even with the help that's alread given within the question.

```
 for i in xrange(1,n/2+1):
        if n%i == 0:
```

I'm not sure how to properly input it so it ended up looking like this

```
def sum_divisors(n):
    for i in xrange(1,n/2+1):
        if n%i == 0:
            sum = 0
        return sum
  # Return the sum of all divisors of n, not including n

print(sum_divisors(0))
# 0
print(sum_divisors(3)) # Should sum of 1
# 1
print(sum_divisors(36)) # Should sum of 1+2+3+4+6+9+12+18
# 55
print(sum_divisors(102)) # Should be sum of 2+3+6+17+34+51
# 114
```

Comment: Why are you using `xrange()`? That was only needed in Python 2.x.

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
def sum_divisors(n):
    sum = 0
    for i in range(1, int(n/2 + 1)):
        if (n % i) == 0:
            sum = sum + i

return sum
```

Be careful: `xrange` is used in Python 2 while `range` is Python 3, more info at this other [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17192158/nameerror-global-name-xrange-is-not-defined-in-python-3).

Answer (score 0):

Use the `sum()` function to add a sequence.

And you only need to go up to the square root of the number, not half the number.

```
from math import sqrt

def sum_divisors(n):
    if n < 1:
        return 0
    return sum(i for i in range(int(sqrt(n))+1) if n % i == 0)
```

Comment: this would give an error if the number is zero

Comment: Added a special check, since it makes no sense to loop for 0

Answer (score 0):

```
def sum_divisors(n):
    sum = 0
    for i in range(n-1):
        i +=1
        if n%i == 0:
            sum += i
    return sum
```

this is quite simple and works